# Flex - Cross domain objects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have an object being passed between flash and flex using the a custom event. I am importing a library in flex containing a copy of the object's class. The classes are identical, but when I attempt to access the object in flex I get this error:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert com.cackleberries.data.api::ApiObject$ to com.cackleberries.data.api.ApiObject.

Any ideas?

This function is passed into flash as a callback from AIR / flex

```
public function airEventHandler(type:String, data:Object):void
{
    switch(type)
    {
            case "air_api_call":
                if(data)
                {
                    if(data.hasOwnProperty("apiObject"))
                    {
                        trace("got air api call event in application");
                        serverApi.makeApiCall(ApiObject(data.apiObject));
                    }
                }
                break;
    }
}
```

I am getting the error when I pass the `ApiObject` to `serverApi.makeApiCall`. That function takes an `ApiObject` as its parameter. Initially, the data object is created with with the `apiObject` key with a `ApiObject` as the value (done in flash).

Comment: What method of passing the data are you using. Show some code.

Comment: Now show the code where you are assigning data.apiObject = ????

Answer (score 0):

The problem's not with `serverApi.makeApiCall`, but with the cast of `data.apiObject` to `ApiObject`.

The reason you're getting this error is because `data.apiObject` is of the type `ApiObject` included in the flash app, while the flex app is using `ApiObject` as included into itself.
Even though the source files are identical, to the player they apparently are not. I think this is because the flex compiler doesn't compile in exactly the same way as the flash compiler, but I'm not 100% on that.

Anyway, to solve this you should use interfaces. Let `ApiObject` implement an `IApiObject` interface with all the necessary methods (ie. the methods the flex app will need) defined in it and then on the flex side cast `data.apiObject` to `IApiObject` instead of `ApiObject`.